# How to create partition function on two columns like integer and datetime

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, sql-server-2017

Can a table be partitioned in two ways?
For example, both with date and with the unit

```
if unit=1 and date > 2021-09-01 save rows in file1.ndf
if unit=1 and date > 2021-10-01 save rows in file2.ndf
if unit=2 and date > 2021-09-01 save rows in file3.ndf
if unit=2 and date > 2021-10-01 save rows in file4.ndf
```

Answer (score 4):

Possible?  Yes.  A good idea?  Perhaps not.

Here is one possible way to use a calculated column to facilitate placing rows onto individual partitions based on a composite value.

Do this in `tempdb`, so we don't inadvertently clobber your work:

```
USE tempdb;
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.Units;
DROP PARTITION SCHEME units_ps;
DROP PARTITION FUNCTION units_pf;
GO
```

Create the partition function:

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION units_pf (varchar(100))
AS RANGE LEFT
FOR VALUES 
(
      '001|20210901'
    , '001|20211001'
    , '002|20210901'
    , '002|20211001'
    , '002|20211101'
    , '003|20210901'
);
GO
```

Create the partition scheme:

```
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME units_ps
AS PARTITION units_pf
ALL TO ([PRIMARY]);
GO
```

Create a table that stores rows using the partition scheme:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.units
(
      [unit]                int                 NOT NULL
    , [date]                datetimeoffset(3)   NOT NULL
    , [blah]                varchar(4000)       NULL
    , [partition_column]    
        AS CONVERT(varchar(100), (RIGHT('000' + CONVERT(varchar(3), [unit], 0), 3) + '|' + CONVERT(varchar(8), [date], 112)), 0)
        PERSISTED
    , CONSTRAINT [units_pk]
        PRIMARY KEY
        CLUSTERED
        ([partition_column])
) ON units_ps([partition_column]);
GO
```

Insert some sample values:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.[units] ([unit], [date], [blah])
VALUES (1, '2021-09-30T00:00:00.000Z', 'row_1')
    , (2, '2021-10-31T00:00:00.000Z', 'row_2')
    , (2, '2021-11-30T00:00:00.000Z', 'row_3');


SELECT *
FROM dbo.[units];
```

| unit | date | blah | partition_column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-09-30 00:00:00.000 +00:00 | row_1 | 001|20210930 |
| 2 | 2021-10-31 00:00:00.000 +00:00 | row_2 | 002|20211031 |
| 2 | 2021-11-30 00:00:00.000 +00:00 | row_3 | 002|20211130 |

Show the partition ranges:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.partition_range_values prv
    INNER JOIN sys.partition_schemes ps ON prv.function_id = ps.function_id
```

| function_id | boundary_id | parameter_id | value | name | data_space_id | type | type_desc | is_default | is_system | function_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 65555 | 1 | 1 | 001|20210901 | units_ps | 65618 | PS | PARTITION_SCHEME | 0 | 0 | 65555 |
| 65555 | 2 | 1 | 001|20211001 | units_ps | 65618 | PS | PARTITION_SCHEME | 0 | 0 | 65555 |
| 65555 | 3 | 1 | 002|20210901 | units_ps | 65618 | PS | PARTITION_SCHEME | 0 | 0 | 65555 |
| 65555 | 4 | 1 | 002|20211001 | units_ps | 65618 | PS | PARTITION_SCHEME | 0 | 0 | 65555 |
| 65555 | 5 | 1 | 002|20211101 | units_ps | 65618 | PS | PARTITION_SCHEME | 0 | 0 | 65555 |
| 65555 | 6 | 1 | 003|20210901 | units_ps | 65618 | PS | PARTITION_SCHEME | 0 | 0 | 65555 |

Show the number of rows in each partition:

```
SELECT ObjectName = QUOTENAME(s.name) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(o.name)
    , p.partition_number
    , p.rows
FROM sys.partitions p
    INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON p.object_id = o.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE s.name = N'dbo'
    AND o.name = N'units'
ORDER BY p.partition_number;
```

| ObjectName | partition_number | rows |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [dbo].[units] | 1 | 0 |
| [dbo].[units] | 2 | 1 |
| [dbo].[units] | 3 | 0 |
| [dbo].[units] | 4 | 0 |
| [dbo].[units] | 5 | 1 |
| [dbo].[units] | 6 | 1 |
| [dbo].[units] | 7 | 0 |